# error while executing fortran file in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: 20.04, lts

Hii experts i am having problem on executing 32 bit binary file in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.There is problem like as given below:

`./mndr`: error while loading shared libraries: `libgfortran.so.3`: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

However i tried a lot using `sudo apt-get install libgfortran3` and `sudo apt-get install lib32gfortran3 libx32gfortran3` but none of the command line works.

My ubuntu version is as below:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: "*I tried ... but none works*" would mean more if you were specific about what "none works" means. Did you get errors when you tried to `apt-get install`, did you `apt-get install` the 32-bit binaries for your program? or didn't specify as per how your question reads (thus the i386 program won't find it!). That package [libgfortran3] I don't see available for *focal* so being specific may help us to help you.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package libgfortran3
error

Comment: my question is...i m getting  error while executiong 32 bit ./mndr     error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: does it require to update the library? if so can anybody suggest which library is require?

Comment: Please edit your question and copy/paste the Fortran code into your question or upload it to any pastebin site and provide a link to it in a comment, so that someone else can try to run the same Fortran code in Ubuntu 20.04.